# DL ATM41 yielded no data

Tags: iot, sensors

I am following the instruction from this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/decentlab/decentlab-decoders) to implement the DL ATM41 Weather sensor onto Element IOT platform. Testing yielded no device id or paket id, as well as no data was shown on the Element IOT platform either.

This is the test result

```
[
  {%{
     data: %{
       air_temperature: 26.4,
       atmospheric_pressure: 95.96,
       battery_voltage: 3.061,
       compass_heading: 86,
       device_id: 858,
       east_wind_speed: 0.04,
       lightning_average_distance: 0,
       lightning_strike_count: 0,
       maximum_wind_speed: 0.2,
       north_wind_speed: 0.08,
       precipitation: 0.0,
       protocol_version: 2,
       relative_humidity: 52.4,
       sensor_temperature_internal: 26.5,
       solar_radiation: 10,
       vapor_pressure: 1.8,
       wind_direction: 29.9,
       wind_speed: 0.09,
       x_orientation_angle: 0.2,
       y_orientation_angle: -2.4
     },
     device_id: nil,
     inserted_at: ~U[2023-07-11 06:52:31.235693Z],
     location: nil,
     measured_at: ~U[2023-07-11 06:52:30.972445Z],
     packet_id: nil
   }, []}
```

What would the problem here be?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.